AWS SDK 1.11 throws the error "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided"
I am using AWS SDK 1.11 and SignatureV4 for C++ in which I am using the below code snippet:
Aws::Http::URI uri = "http://ip-address:port/bucketname/test//file.txt";
Aws::Client::StreamOutcome outcome = MakeRequestWithUnparsedResponse(uri, request, Aws::Http::HttpMethod::HTTP_GET);
if (outcome.IsSuccess())
   return true;
else
   return false;

Here, as you can see that the object is test//file.txt, which means there is a directory test under which there is another directory by name / and file.txt is present within this directory. In AWS SDk 1.7, the URI I gave was taken as it is but in AWS SDK 1.11, it is normalizing the multiple slashes to single slash resulting in below URI;
http://ip-address:port/bucketname/test/file.txt
I tried to percent encode the double slashes but it is returning an error as "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided". But, when I percent encode for any other special characters, it is successful as Aws::Http::URI is now requiring the special characters to be percent encoded.
Percent encodes I tried for test//file.txt:

test%2F%2Ffile.txt
test%2F/%2F/file.txt
test/%2F/file.txt

Can anybody please assist on this if I should encode it in any other percent encoding way to make sure that it is accepted?
Many Thanks
